# Handle exception in powershell

Tags: powershell, exception, performancecounter

I have a config file when you can add a list of performance counters, for example :

```
\Memory\Page Faults/sec
\Memory\Available Bytes
\ASP.NET Applications(*)\Requests in Application Queue
```

I have a powershell script, that parses the file and does a Get-Counter parameter where parameter is each counter in my config file. Everything works well, but I would like my script to be able to handle exception when an user add a bad counter, for example :

```
\Memory\Page Faults/sec
\Memory\Available Bytes
\ASP.NET Applications(*)\Requests in Application Queue
ddftrigjgigjij
```

With this, I get a red exception in my powershell console which I would like to replace with an appropiate message like "counter not found". I am beginning with powershell and I tried to use try\catch without success.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Get-Counter`, this will make try/catch work as you expect:

```powershell
try{
    Get-Counter "bogus counter" -ErrorAction stop
} 
catch { 
    echo "counter not found"
}
```